# Accordion Simple Multiple jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have the following accordion at first sight works fine, but when you close or click on the titles (h3) all close and not to be pertener.

It was a way to segregate each accordion that works independently of others.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="accordion">
     <h3>Lorem 1</h3>

    <div>Text-1</div>
     <h3>Lorem 2</h3>

    <div>Text-2</div>
     <h3>Lorem 3</h3>

    <div>Text-3</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
     <h3>Lorem 6</h3>

    <div>Text-6</div>
     <h3>Lorem 7</h3>

    <div>Text-7</div>
     <h3>Lorem 8</h3>

    <div>Text-8</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
     <h3>Lorem 12</h3>

    <div>Text-12</div>
     <h3>Lorem 13</h3>

    <div>Text-13</div>
     <h3>Lorem 14</h3>

    <div>Text-14</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
    $(".accordion").each(function () {
        $(this).find("h3:first").addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        $(this).find("h3").click(function () {
            if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                $('.accordion h3').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
                $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3y1b58hh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling $(.accordion h3), that is not connected to $(this) and will trigger all .accordion. Use:

```
        $(".accordion").each(function () {
        $(this).find("h3:first").addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        $(this).find("h3").click(function () {
            if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
                  $(this).parent().find("h3").removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
                $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```